# Nodejs app working on localhost but crashes on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

My nodejs app is working on localhost but when deployed with heroku, it crashes showing me one new module or the other that it cannot find. What do I do?

Comment: Could you provide logs ( heroku logs)?

Comment: Check modules are in `package.json`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, please make sure that you provide as much relevant information as possible. We can't help with code we can't see based on error messages that we can't see. [ask] has some great tips on asking questions effectively here.